# Excel Formula to replace conditionally at the end of a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Trying to do a mass replace o of cells only ending in " A" in a data set. This keeps coming up value error

=IF(RIGHT(A1,2)=" A",REPLACE(" A", RIGHT(A1, 1),2, " Away"), "not recognized")

Comment: Did you actually  look up the reference for REPLACE formula? REPLACE(old_text,start_num,num_chars,new_text)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Skip the replace:

```
=IF(RIGHT(A1,2)=" A", A1 & "way", "not recognized")
```

If you really want to use it:

```
=IF(RIGHT(A1,2)=" A",REPLACE(A1,LEN(A1)-1,2," Away"), "not recognized")
```